# Implementing optional argument of an variadic-using function?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, variadic

I have a function:

```
log(const char *domain, int log_level, const char *fmt, ...)
```

I would like first and second arguments optional, so it's like following calls would be possible:

```
log("SYSTEM-A", 1, "Example %s", "...message");
log(1, "Example %s", "...message");
log("Example %s", "...message");
```

I've read about neat macro tricks, however they (almost?) all rely on trailing arguments to 'stand out' in a helper macro:

```
HELPER_SELECT(_1, _2, _3, func, ...) func
```

I however cannot use this method, because `log()` can take arbitrary number of variadic arguments. Is this possible to overcome somehow? With use of `_Generics`, maybe?

Comment: What would the function do when those args are missing? Can you not just have macros that fill the missing args with default values. e.g `LOG_NO_DOMAIN(level, fmt, ...) log(NULL, level, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)`?

Comment: Do not use `log` as a function name as it is a standard C function for taking natural logarithm.

Comment: How can the function know whether or not the second provided argument is "optional" or not? It can't. Not in C.

Comment: Somewhat doable.  Yet case 1 and 3 lack distinctiveness as both start with `const char *` then an `int` or _maybe_ an `int`.  Consider how `log("Ex %d %s", 42, "message");` looks like the `log(const char *domain, int log_level, const char *fmt)`.  Overall I see OP's goal as possible, but a lot of work as code needs to parse the first parameter for `%specifiers`.  Recommend alternative goals.

Comment: how would you differentiate `log("SYSTEM-A", 1, "Example")` from `log("Example %d%s", 1, "...message")` ?

Comment: Solution from @KamilCuk is very interesting – it correctly recognizes `log("A",1,"B")` from `log("B")` and `log("%s","C")` by utilizing 2 tricks – `_Generic`) to recognize `log(1,"A")` and `strstr(…,"%")`. The special case of `log("B")` is addressed by argument count equal 1, while the `log("%s","C")` by the `strstr` – if there are more arguments than 1, then the first string *has* to include `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> (1) log("SYSTEM-A", 1, "Example %s", "...message");
> (2) log(1, "Example %s", "...message");
> (3) log("Example %s", "...message");
> ```

From what I understand:

- (1) does not has `%` in it's first argument.
- (2) first argument is int
- (3) has `%` in it's argument.

You can:

- overload `log` macro on number of arguments
- if one argument

  - choose (3)
- else
- _Generic on first argument
- If first argument is an int

  - choose (2)
- Else

  - call some `_log_wrapper(const char *arg, ...)`

    - inspect if `strchr(arg, '%')`

      - if it does, call va_list version of (3)
    - if it does not, call va_list version of (1)

A possible implementation looks like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void vlog_domain(const char *domain, int log_level, const char *fmt, va_list va)  {
    printf("domain\n");
}
void vlog_level(int log_level, const char *fmt, va_list va) {
    printf("level\n");
}
void vlog_normal(const char *fmt, va_list va) {
    printf("normal\n");
}

void _log_wrapper(int type, ...) {
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, type);
    if (type == 1) {
        int log_level = va_arg(va, int);
        const char *fmt = va_arg(va, const char *);
        vlog_level(log_level, fmt, va);
    } else {
        const char *arg = va_arg(va, const char*);
        if (!strchr(arg, '%')) {
            const char *domain = arg;
            int log_level = va_arg(va, int);
            const char *fmt = va_arg(va, const char*);
            vlog_domain(domain, log_level, fmt, va);
        } else {
            const char *fmt = arg;
            vlog_normal(fmt, va);
        }
    }
    va_end(va);
}

#define _log_1(_1)  vlog_normal(_1) // TODO
#define _log_2(_1, ...)  _log_wrapper( \
        _Generic((_1), int: 1, char *: 2), _1, ##__VA_ARGS__)
// this implementation supports max ca. 10 arguments
#define _log_N(_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,_0,N,...)  _log_##N
#define log(...)  _log_N(__VA_ARGS__,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    log("SYSTEM-A", 1, "Example %s", "...message"); // domain
    log(1, "Example %s", "...message"); // level
    log("Example %s", "...message"); // normal
}
```

These are some time spent on writing the interface, that the next developer will most probably anyway not understand and will have to rewrite and refactor the whole code. I suggest instead to be as possible clear and write as possibly easy code to understand and just name your functions:

```
 logd("SYSTEM-A", 1, "Example %s", "...message");
 logl(1, "Example %s", "...message");
 log("Example %s", "...message");
```

and be done with it.

Inspect other projects how they solved logging with "domain+loglevel" (which sounds like `syslog()` severity and facility....) have a look how other projects solved logging interface. From my mind I enjoyed [zephyr project solved logging](https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/reference/logging/index.html), and it's open source so see inspect it's sources.

Comment: Thanks for such interesting and creative solution. I've implemented it and it is working :) I've only changed so that there is only *wrapper* function and pass a different type when a single argument is only given (`log_normal` case in your code). And now I'm thinking about even more distinct syntax for the `log` function, having so nice `_Generic` use – typically, _Generic is a bloat, large code but here it isn't :) So, what to pass for first argument? Some user data, or maybe – a GError from GLib? That's cool, I could then append its message in a standard way :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible in C - variadic functions solve this problem once, but you're trying to solve it twice.

Consider the use of a simple options structure. Have all options *empty value* be equivalent to `0` (or have a default initializer), so that the caller doesn't need to remember any sentinel values.

```
struct loggeropts {
    const char *domain;
    int level;
};

void logger(struct loggeropts *opts, const char *fmt, ...) {
    if (opts) {
        if (opts->domain) { /* */ }
        if (opts->level) { /* */ }
    }

    /* impl */
}

int main(void) {
    struct loggeropts opts = { .domain = "SYSTEM-A" };            
                                                                                                                      
    logger(&opts, "#Example %u %s", 42, "information");                                                               
    logger(NULL, "#Example %u %s", 44, "different information");
}
```

If optional arguments aren't used that often, you could hide the call behind a macro.

```
#define logger(string, ...) logger_with_opts(NULL, string, __VA_ARGS__)
void logger_with_opts(struct loggeropts *opts, const char *fmt, ...);
```

---

Alternatively, have a special section of your format string that identifies passed options, and make sure they are passed before the usual variadic arguments. Remembering to move your `fmt` pointer before passing it onward. This does seem fragile, though, and has additional overhead.

```
logger("{{@d@l}}Example %s", "SYSTEM-A", 1, "...message");
logger("{{@d}}Example %s", "SYSTEM-B", "...message");
```

---

I would most likely suggest just simply having domain-specific logging functions, in addition to the general purpose function.